# i can not run project in apcelerator in emeulator

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a problem when i tried to run any project in an android emulator
I have installed adb and jdk version 1.7 
when i type this command in the terminal
    $ appc ti info -t android
I got

```
Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = not found
  SDK Path                    = not found

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = not found
  NDK Version                 = not found

Android Platforms
  None

Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  None
```

although the dashboard shows that the android is installed.

When I need more than this I want to run the project in an external device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install android SDK and configure the the path in Appcelerator Studio. Android SDK have have many different parts and add-ons. Please go through the documentation before downloading.
[Documentation Link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK)

Comment: thanks for your answer , i installed the android studio and android sdk , i made new project in android studio and run it in the emulator , and every thing works fine , but now when i set the path of the sdk in the preferences ->platform->android i got this error "no adroid sdks found in the selected path" , how can if fix that

Comment: Please make sure you add the right path. It should be the path where all android tools is present.

Comment: Thanks again , i already add the right path , because i bring the path from the Android Studio , the emulator runs correctly in android studio so i do not know where is the problem. another question , when i connect a device to the laptop and i have set the settings of the device to allow USB debugging , and allow install from unknown sources , no devices displayed in the run from device screen